# Delete overlapping Shortest Path curves in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I made a tree with Geometry Nodes using `Shortest Path`. With this method, there are a lot of overlapping curves that make the final mesh very unecessarily dense (not good for performance).

[image: curves overlapping in the edges shortest path]

I'm trying to find a solution to delete curves that are smaller and share the same points position (or edges if it is converted to mesh for this operation) compared to a longer curve in the same position... Or any better solution to have a clean mesh in the final result...

In my research I found a video that aims in that direction: https://youtu.be/MSZobqlYJWY

But it isn't a very good option because I have thousands of overlapping points, and we don't have loop operations in Geometry Nodes...

I'm also using Blender 3.41 so `Transfer Attribute` isn't available... I tried to use the `Sample` nodes, Index and Nearest, but can't get the result right.

Someone, help?

**Here is the blend file for those willing to help:**

[image]

Comment: Hello, welcome. Please show us your Geometry Nodes setup with screenshots, it's unlikely people can really tell what's the problem just by looking at the final result. Sharing your file on blend-exchange.com would be even better.

Comment: Actually this isn't a problem... It is the way the shortest edge path works...

I have the start point aiming to an empty, and the end point aiming to some random vertices at the top of a mesh grid of edges. So from the start point until the end point, some paths is overlaping with others, since they started at the same position. My goal is to find a solution to delete any overlaping points to have a clean mesh in the final result. :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across a hack solution that might work in certain cases. Merge by distance node, which only works for meshes, can be used here with curve to mesh into merge by distance into mesh to curve if you don't provide any curve profile for curve to mesh.

Even though it messes the curves orientation after the merge as it probably has to interpolate the normals from both of the curves, or something. Not an expert by any means.

Comment: Yeah! I tried this hack. Like you said for some cases it may work. Storing some curve attributes before transforming it into mesh for merge the distances and then transfer these attributes aftwards, may work... 

The problem with tree's generation (that is my case) is that the merge by distance disconnect the curve points and then when you need to use the curve profile to generate the mesh, you'll have several disconected pieces that break the tree shape.

Until now I didnt find a optimal way to generate a clean tree mesh using the shortest edge path... :/